# (Mutators ou Middlewares) Qual seria o ideal utilizar na hora de converter uma string antes de inserir no banco de dados no laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Qual seria mais recomendado utilizar na hora de manipular uma string que nesse caso seria o (,) para o (.) na hora de inserir um valor na base de dados (MySQL) do tipo decimal no Laravel?

1 - Utilizando um middleware customizado

```
class convertCommaInDot extends TransformsRequest
{

    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return str_replace(',','.',$value);
    }
}
```

Chamando o middleware no arquivo route/web.php

```
Route::post('/numeros/add', 'NumeroControlador@store')->name('number.store')
    ->middleware('CommaInDot');
```

OU

2 - Utilizando o mutator setNumeroAttribute($value), nesse caso não necessita utilizar o middleware.

```
class Numero extends Model
{

    public function getNumeroAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['numero'] = str_replace('.',',',$value);
    }

    public function setNumeroAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['numero'] = str_replace(',','.',$value);
    }
}
```

Ambos geram o mesmo resultado ou seja, eu insiro no formulário um numero 1,23 e automaticamente o valor é transformado para 1.23

Comment: Mutator é para alterar dado; middleware é para lidar com mensagens HTTP. Então, mutator é a resposta.

Comment: Igor por curiosidade esse TranformesRequest é um pacote?

Comment: Na versão 6 existe `middleware` que tira espaço de texto, por exemplo, então, eu vejo assim qual é a melhor forma vai depender porque o `framework` abriu uma brecha ! a sua versão é a 5 ou 6 (especifica certinho)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sobre o TransformsRequest, ela é uma classe que o Laravel utiliza para criar o middleware ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu utilizo o laravel 6.

Comment: Sim acabei achando ... eu acho que a sua pergunta pode ser feita das duas formas o Laravel tem isso, mas, claro que com configurações e um código apropriado

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @AndersonCarlosWoss , agradeço.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic hm, entendi, obrigado por colaborar mano!!

Comment: Porque assim Igor essa middleware você pode fazer por rotas (verbo `post`,`put`) onde essa rota tem dados que serão formatados/validados a sua maneira. (é uma ideia inicial, estou na rua, mas, a noite vou dar uma olhda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como eu gosto sempre ter uma ideia sobre o que cada coisa faz eu resolvi fazer um exemplo, o `middleware` que herda da classe [TransformsRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php) tem uma função global que é executado na pilha geral de `middleware` da aplicação [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

Inclusive esse tipo de `middleware` é chamado no `array` global:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,         
    ];
```

e esse `middleware` não deve ser configurado nas ***rotas*** porque a sua função como citado é global.

Para o seu problema, não deveria ser usado, porque, ele confere cada item enviado na sua requisição e se for satisfeito a troca de ponto por virgula, é feito em todos os campos que fazem parte dessa regra e isso não é bom, já pessou ter um nome com ponto, *exemplo* ***Stack.OverFlow*** ele vai substituir sumariamente por virgula ficando ***Stack,OverFlow*** e não é isso que você quer, você só precisa mudar onde for número com virgula, então, [TransformsRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php) só deve ser usado quando essa mudança ocorrer em todos os valores enviados na sua requisição, que no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) atual versão 6 (até essa data) tem dois [TransformsRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php) globais que são:

- [TrimStrings.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php)
- [ConvertEmptyStringsToNull](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php)

No seu caso é melhor utilizar [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) igual está na sua pergunta com uma mudança no seu código para verificar também ***milhar*** e deixar o valor original sem mudança, somente traga a mudança quando for resgatada, ***exemplo***:

```
class Numero extends Model
{
    public function getNumeroAttribute($value)
    {
        return str_replace(['.',',']],['','.'], $value); // mudança aqui.
    }
    public function setNumeroAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['numero'] = str_replace(',','.', $value);
    }
}
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)
- [TransformsRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php)
- [TrimStrings.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php)
- [ConvertEmptyStringsToNull](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php)

Comment: Hm... , então pelo que eu entendi, o uso do TransformsRequest é válido apenas para middlewares globais que é o caso do  TrimStrings e ConvertEmptyStringsToNull, e que no meu caso não seria interessante,  já que o meu objetivo era aplicar em rotas específicas, e que nesse caso o mais recomendado seria o Mutator. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: é que o `TransformsRequest` seria para todos os itens da requisição, eu não acho válido então para trocar valores monetários ...

Comment: @IgorAC se for útil sinalize como resposta da sua pergunta